# Не повлияет ли на индексацию такой редирект?

Tags: веб-программирование, redirect, поисковые-системы

У меня многоязычный сайт. Язык по умолчанию - русский. Поэтому когда ввести в адресную строку site.ru, произойдет редирект 301 на site.ru/ru/. Не навредит ли такой прием при индексации сайта поисковиками?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метатег языка hreflang лучше, чем редиректить. Пусть лучше ПСы, отдают нужную языковую версию клиенту. Все равно, они лучше определят по настройкам пользователя язык :)